# How do I put a File from my Cache directory in an ImageView on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-file

I have the following code to get my JPG file from a directory on my Android device:

```
File f = new File(cacheDir, fn);
```

How do I take `f` and put it in an ImageView?

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.imvCover);

// what call do I make here?
// this obviously is not correct and just for example.
imgView.setToFile(f);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.
Since you are having a file object use the below code.

This may help you

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is correct, no?

```
Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
imgView.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: what is `fn`? @ethan allen